# Is same background for two different headings possible ? (RGB keyboard-like effect)

Tags: html, css

I'm planning on creating a CSS version of the RGB keyboard. Make a text gradient is easy, but to really 'SYNC' that gradient between headings is impossible to me right now. Is there a way to achieve this kind of result?

[image]

I tried individual gradient animation and blend mode, but still can't figure a way out.

I used background-clip and achieved beautiful gradient animation for individual headings, but the gradients are 'individual', not synced as an RGB keyboard...

Comment: wrap it in a `div` and apply the gradient as the background color for that parent `div`?

Comment: Not that easy. The problem is the 'keycaps' means the headings. I mean syncing the 'color' of the headings.

Comment: Sounds like you want some `javascript` and some math to calculate the gradient instead of just using a broad gradient background?

Comment: I think so.. I don't think pure CSS will solve this...

Comment: `SVG` might be able to get you there. I believe you can animate them and therefore fake it but still get the same result. Either way, definitely not easy. Good luck.

Comment: I still don't get it! What do you exactly want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
.keyboard {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f00, #ff0, #0f0, #0ff, #00f, #f0f, #f00);
  display: inline-block;
}

.key {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin: 5px;

  /* THE IMPORTANT STUFF */
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="keyboard">
  <div class="key">A</div>
  <div class="key">B</div>
  <div class="key">C</div>
  <div class="key">D</div>
  <div class="key">E</div>
  <div class="key">...</div>
</div>
```

When setting the color to white (`#fff`) and the background-color to black (`#000`) on the keys and then set the `mix-blend-mode` to `multiply` then the background (`background-color`) remains black and the foreground (`color`) gets whatever value the background of the container is becuse:

```
color c;
c x white === c
c x black === black
```

Comment: Wow!!. Thank you very much!! Sorry for the late thank :) !